# Web crawling extracts same sentence twice

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

When I write the below code, as you can see in the picture, the result shows me the same sentence twice.
How can I solve this problem?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://www.consumeraffairs.com/education/online-courses/coursera.html?page=2#scroll_to_reviews=true")

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser') 

data = soup.find_all('p') 
for item in data:  
    print(item.string)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Changing your parser to `lxml` will fix this.

By inspecting the website, you will see there are empty p tags around the p tag of the reviews, and they are messing up the html parser.

[image: Empty p tags around review p tag]

This snippet change on the first line will fix by changing your parser, and then on the data list, you can filter the empty p tags by seeing if they have content in their string attribute.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://www.consumeraffairs.com/education/online-courses/coursera.html?page=2#scroll_to_reviews=true")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")

data = soup.find_all('p')

for item in data:
    if item.string:
        print(item.string)
```

This will print for you the reviews only once!

If you get an error about not having a builder, run

```
pip install lxml
```

Comment: Thank you so much Arson. Even the tip of lxml installation tip:) 
However, when I followed your advice and run `soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")`, I received this error message. 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'content'

Do you know what the problem is and may I ask for your help again?

Comment: sorry, you need to keep the other lines of the code. If it's saying NoneType it means you didn't run the res= request.get(...). I just put the lines that needed to change, the others must stay.

Comment: ...said more simply...`response` has the value `None`.  It's hard to know just what is going on since the symbol `response` doesn't even show up in your question's code.  Maybe you mean to reference `res` rather than `response`, like you did in the code you provided?

Comment: Oops! You are right CryptoFool.
It was my mistake to change the variable name from res to response. 
Thank you!

Comment: @Arson0
I followed your suggestion and solve the problem. Thank you so much. 
By the way, I wanted to crawl several pages not one page. Can I crawl with the request library or should I use selenuim and deiver.get() function?

Comment: If you feel confident, try scrapy. It is by far the simplest route for web scraping, while also having all the functionalities. Requests + Beautiful Soup can only get you up to a certain point, after that you have to either go with Selenium, Scrapy or other tools. I pretty much prefer to use Selenium to test things, and Scrapy to do web scraping!

Comment: No problem @Genie. If you feel the answer suits your question would you mind selecting it so the question is closed? Good luck with web scraping!